# Batch convert WP files to MSWord

Tags: conversion

My goal is to try and convert a large number of files in
Word Perfect X5 to MSWord files.

I would like have either a macro that will do this that I can run in Word Perfect (I need it to run in WP).

or

I would prefer to have a command prompt that can be set up so I can start a recursive batch system that will do the word perfect conversion to word for me.

My files will be on my C:/ and the converted ones will also stay in the same place.